# $\mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ homeomorphic to cylinder in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology

I need to show that $M = \mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is homemorphic to the cylinder $Z = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1\}$

My idea is to exhibit an embedding of $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ that restricts to an homeomorphism onto $Z$.

I defined:
$$F: M \to \mathbb{R}^3, \ F(\rho,[x]) = (\cos(2\pi [x]),\sin(2\pi [x]),\log(\rho))$$
$F$ is well-defined, injective and continuous and $F(M) = Z$.

To conclude I have to show that $F|_Z = M \to Z$ is open/closed.
I feel lost because $M$ is not compact.

I tried "by hand" with no success. I thought also about showing properness, but even that didn't work. Constructing the inverse is not practical since trigonometric functions are not so good. Ideas?

Comment: Hint: To prove that the inverse is continuous, you only have to prove continuity locally. For which purpose the trigonometric functions and their inverses are perfectly good.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks